# Watir-webdriver can't click on visible link which appears in popup

Tags: ruby, firefox, watir

I am using watir-webdriver + ruby + rspec + gem parallel_tests.

And my test case has to be able to cancel and then delete item from items list. "Cancel" and "Delete" links appears from pop-up menu. 
Following method verifies cancel link `gear_dropdown_menu.cancel_job = browser.link(:text, 'Cancel')` is visible.

```
  Timer.repeat_until_true(30, 1) do
    sleep 1
    gear_dropdown_menu.cancel_job.visible?
  end
```

When link appeared and I can see it, next I try to click it using such code:

```
  browser.execute_script("
    id = $('div.job-actions:visible').data('id');
    $('a[href*=\"jobs/'+ id +'/cancel\"]').show().click()
  ")

div.job-actions:visible - actions popup, where links are placed
```

I use data-id attribute to specify direct link href. But it looks like watir can't see it.

The problem is when I execute tests in parallel, 2 from 3 tries it fails.
When I execute test non-parallel, looks overall good.

What may be the cause of the problem?

Updated: add code of popup. It's not a separate window. Just hidden div element which appears when I click a button.

```
 <div class="job-actions" data-id="8769" style="top: 329px; right: 0px; display: block;">
  <section>
    <header>Actions</header>
    <ul>
            <li class="pause">
              <a href="http://host.com/jobs/8769/pause">Pause Job</a>
            </li>
          <li class="cancel">
            <a href="http:/host.com/jobs/8769/cancel" class="cancel">Cancel Job</a>
          </li>
          </ul>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm curious why you're hand-rolling your own [`wait_until_present`](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/watir-webdriver/Watir/EventuallyPresent:wait_until_present) method?  Also, posting the minimal amount of HTML to replicate the issue (as well as the error stacktraces) will make it easier for people to reproduce your problem.

Comment: @orde because standard method doesn't work each time. Sorry for no html.

Comment: but it sounds like your own method also does not work each time.  maybe you would be better off looking closer at why wait_until_present is not working for you?

Comment: WHY oh why oh why are you using javascript to click something?  is that how normal users interact with your system?

Comment: @ChuckvanderLinden because I had no idea why it doesn't work. And yes, it seems that problem is not in `while_until_present` method. Any other advices?

Answer (score 3):

(text: 'Cancel') is going to match the first cancel button on your list. If you are running tests in parallel you are likely getting race conditions to cancel/delete the same items from the list.

A couple other tips:
You don't have to use Timer. Your code is functionally equivalent to the built in method:

`gear_dropdown_menu.cancel_job.wait_until_present`

Also, is your popup a separate window? If so, you don't need to use execute_script (which should be avoided when possible). you can use:

`browser.window(title: 'Your Popup Title').use { browser.link(href: /cancel/).click }` (or whatever selector makes sense)

Answer (score 0):

If your problem only occurs when running in parallel then it sounds like you may have either dependencies or interferences between tests, which end up creating a race condition.

If you are doing Create, Update, Delete type operations, then each test needs to work with unique objects, created with unique identifiers (names? id's? ) if not then either an object might not exist when you need it (not created yet, deleted, etc) or you could run into conflicts caused because the object names/identifiers are not unique (so a test could re-create a new copy of an object another test just deleted, causing the second test to think the delete failed, etc)

Without seeing a LOT more of your code it would be difficult to give you more precise advice, but in my experience when something works when done in series, but not if the order is altered, or the test run solo, or tests run in parallel, then you likely have dependencies between tests, or a situation like one test deleting something before the other test can try to cancel or update the same something.

Comment: the problem appears occasionally not depends on parallel or serial execution. It can work 5 times from 5, and can work 4 times from 5. And yeah, it works with different objects. And I verified that in visual mode. I think one of the problems may be headless mode, which is running on CI